# why is my residential cold water in pressure reducer valve corroding like a battery terminal?

Tags: plumbing

my pressure reducer valve to my appartment is corroding on the outside like the build up you get on an automobile batery? is this any indication that the water is toxic? what would cause this? improberly installed electrical ground? no dielectric fiting at my hotwater tank? hard water? is my electricity to the apartment rickling down the drain?
the other 3 pressure reducer valves in line with mine are all fine only mine is corroding.

Comment: Could you post a photo?

Answer (score 3):

That could be galvanic corrosion, what metals are involved?

But if the others are fine and are made of the same metal, then it could just be a simple leak.

Maybe post a photo.